# Converting a string into a list

Tags: string, list

I have the following string:

```
['####\n# .#\n#  ###\n#*@  #\n#  $ #\n#  ###\n####']
```

and I want to convert it into a list with sublists, where each sublist includes the text before the `"\n"`, meaning I'm trying to make it look like this:

```
['#### ,'# .#, '#  ###', '#*@  #', '#  $ #', '#  ###', '####']
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Judging from the question history [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288250/how-to-exceute-def-command-without-showing-none), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126594/how-do-i-move-to-the-next-index), I'm guessing Python.

Comment: I think the expected output is missing a few quotes. It's not valid syntax for a list of strings.

Answer (score 3):

Most languages (and I'm guessing this is Python) have a [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function for this purpose:

```
result = yourString.split("\n");
```

Note that `['###...###']` is not a string but a *list containing a string*.

Answer (score 0):

in perl:

```
my $your_string = "['####\n# .#\n# ###\n#@ #\n# $ #\n# ###\n####']";
my @list = split (/\\n/, $your_string);

print join (', ', @list) . "\n";
```